# Spring @OneToMany problems

Tags: java, spring, annotations, one-to-many

Doing a project with parcel service. I created OrderItem API and Dispatcher API. Now, I want to connect then by relations. The idea is: dispatcher can have many orderItems. OrderItem can only have one dispatcher. If you delete dispatcher, his order items also has to go out.
I have already created a little bit, but I'm so messed up here and can't finish this thing logically. Would someone give me some ideas on how I should attack this problem.

Do I need to put relations both sides or only to one of them?

When do I need to create constructors with arguments? Because in entity class you have to have no arg constructors...?

**OrderItem class:**

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Order weight is required")
    private String weight;
    @NotBlank(message = "Order dimensions are required")
    private String dimensions;
    @NotBlank(message = "Order origin is required")
    private String origin;
    @NotBlank(message = "Order destination is required")
    private String destination;
    @NotNull(message = "Order comment cannot be null")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public OrderItem() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public void setDimensions(String dimensions) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Dispatcher getDispatcher() {
        return dispatcher;
    }

    public void setDispatcher(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }
}
```

**OrderController class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    OrderService service;

    @Autowired
    private MapValidationErrorService mapValidationErrorService;

    @GetMapping("/{dispatcherId}/orders")
    public List<OrderItem> getAllOrderItems(@PathVariable int dispatcherId) {
        return service.getAllOrderItems(dispatcherId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/{dispatcherId}/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveOrder(@Valid @RequestBody OrderItem orderItem, @PathVariable int dispatcherId, BindingResult result) {

        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) {
            return errorMap;
        }

        orderItem.setDispatcher(new Dispatcher(dispatcherId, "", "", ""));
        service.insertOrUpdate(orderItem);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Order was created successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateOrder(@Valid @RequestBody OrderItem orderItem, BindingResult result) {

        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) {
            return errorMap;
        }

        service.insertOrUpdate(orderItem);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Order was updated successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<OrderItem> getAllOrders() {
        return service.findAllOrders();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteOrder(@PathVariable int orderId) {

        if (service.findById(orderId) == null) {
            throw new CustomErrorException("Order doesn't exist, check order id");
        }

        service.deleteOrder(orderId);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Order with ID " + orderId + " was deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrderItem> getOrderById(@PathVariable int orderId) {
        OrderItem item = service.findById(orderId);

        if (service.findById(orderId) == null) {
            throw new CustomErrorException("Order id not found - " + orderId);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<OrderItem>(item, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Dispatcher class:**

```
@Entity
public class Dispatcher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Dispatcher first name is required")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Dispatcher last name is required")
    private String lastName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Dispatcher email name is required")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "Dispatcher email is required")
    private String password;
    @NotBlank(message = "Dispatcher phone number is required")
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Dispatcher() {

    }

    public Dispatcher(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

**DispatcherController class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dispatcher")
public class DispatcherController {

    @Autowired
    DispatcherService service;

    @Autowired
    private MapValidationErrorService mapValidationErrorService;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveDispatcher(@Valid @RequestBody Dispatcher dispatcher, BindingResult result) {

        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) {
            return errorMap;
        }

        service.insertOrUpdate(dispatcher);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Dispatcher was created successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Dispatcher> getAllDispatchers() {
        return service.findAllDispatchers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{dispatcherId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDispatcherById(@PathVariable int dispatcherId) {

        Dispatcher dispatcher = service.findById(dispatcherId);

        if (service.findById(dispatcherId) == null) {
            throw new CustomErrorException("Dispatcher id not found - " + dispatcherId);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Dispatcher>(dispatcher, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{dispatcherId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteDispatcher(@PathVariable int dispatcherId) {

        if (service.findById(dispatcherId) == null) {
            throw new CustomErrorException("Dispatcher doesn't exist, check dispatcher id");
        }

        service.deleteDispatcher(dispatcherId);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Order with ID " + dispatcherId + " was deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateDispatcher(@Valid @RequestBody Dispatcher dispatcher, BindingResult result) {

        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) {
            return errorMap;
        }

        service.insertOrUpdate(dispatcher);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Dispatcher was updated successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have defined the relationship incorrectly. And yes you need to have no-args constructor. This helps hibernate to map the values from database to java objects when retrieving data from the database

Assuming you are going for a uni-directional mapping,

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = <foriegn_key_column in orderItem table i.e. id>)
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;
}

@Entity
public class Dispatcher {

    private List<OrderItem > orders;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that bidirectional relationship gives you access in both directions. so that you can access the other side without any queries. It works for cascade actions too.

The bidirectional `@OneToMany` generates better DML because the `@ManyToOne` owns the relationship.

Unidirectional `@ManyToOne`or bidirectional `@OneToMany` are more efficient than unidirectional `@OneToMany`.

Before JPA 2.0 this unidirection `@OneToMany` used a join table to manage the association between parent and child rows. So higher cost in read (3 tables join) and write (3 tables insertion).

Since JPA 2.0 for unidirectional `@OneToMany` you should use it in correlation with `@JoinColumn`

With the `@JoinColumn` the `@OneToMany` association controls the child table FK.. and so no need for extra junction table.

But performance wise there is no better than bidirectional associations.

Pros of unidirectional `@OneToMany` -> simplicity.

For your second question : NoArg is required only by the persistence framework (Hibernate for e.g). But you can (and should) use your own constructors to create `consistent` objects.